# Using PHP to read and write to JSON

Tags: php, json

So currently I'm working on a project that requires the use of PHP and JSON. The way I have currently set up my code is so that I read the JSON file in using file_get_contents and then use the built in json_decode() function. Everything is reading perfectly, it's the writing part that is giving me trouble.

The way I have my JSON tree set up is:

```
{
"test":[
        {
        "testName":"Winter 2011",
        "testDate":"12/04/2011",
        "testTime":"2:00pm",
        "testRoom":"room",
        "cap": 10,
        "spotsLeft": 0,
        "student":[
            {
                "fname":"Bob",
                "lname":"Roberts",
                "usrnm":"bobr",
                "email":"bob@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

To get the right test (since there will be multiple tests) I'm using a `foreach loop` and then I make sure there isn't a duplicate. At this point I'm ready to add a new student to the JSON file so I call:
`

```
$file = file_get_contents('testDates.json');
$json = json_decode($file, true);

//Go through each test in the file
foreach ($json[test] as $t){
   .....
   //Works if I only do $t[student] but that only adds it to the $t[] and not the
   //JSON file. Can't seem to get it to add to the whole JSON string.
   array_push($json[$t][student], $newStudent);
   echo json_encode($json);
   .....
   //Use a file_put_contents later to write the file out
```

Any thoughts would be extremely helpful. It's probably a pointer error to a certain point int he array but a second set of eyes never hurt. Thanks.

Comment: As a point of style, use `$array[] = $value` instead of `array_push($array, $value)`. It's clearer and more idiomatic.  Also, quote your key names--this is a syntax error that happens to work as long as no constant with that name is defined.

Comment: Thanks Francis, I had disabled warnings on my server for some reason. Quoted all of my JSON references though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$t` is a copy, it is not referencing original object. This appens with every foreach cycle. Use instead:

```
foreach ($json[test] as $k => $t){
    array_push($json[test][$k][student], $newStudent);
    ...
}
```

Or you can try:

```
foreach ($json[test] as &$t){
    array_push($t[student], $newStudent);
    ...
}
```

See here to learn how foreach works: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: +1 But you need to be careful when using references in loops. When the loop finishes $t is still a reference to the last element. If you use $t again i.e. assign it a new value or use it in another loop you'll end up with hard to debug problems. The solution is to unset the reference after the loop. `foreach( $collection as &$item ) { /*do stuff*/ }; unset( $item );`

Comment: Great! I knew it was something with referencing the temporary value `$t` but using the reference worked like a charm. Thanks lorenzo-s!

@meouw I am calling this PHP script once per submission. So will the values hold even though I am calling it on different occasions? aka I'm not modify the PHP file so it should remain the same and re-initialize the variables every time the button is pushed right?

Comment: @Will references only last for one script execution. If you don't use the reference again you don't have a problem. It's good practice to delete the reference tho, at some later date you or another developer may use the variable again cause problems.

Comment: @meouw Alright, I'll make sure to `unset` at the end of my loop. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: In fact, I prefer the first solution I suggested, using key to access array element (instead of using a dangerous reference). Anyway, could you accept my answer, Will? :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong $json[$t] inside foreach instead of $json["test"][$t] and also you need to use key-value pairs

```
$testVal = $json["test"];
foreach ($testVal as $key => $val){
    . . .
    array_push($testVal[$key]["student"], $newStudent);
    . . .
}
```

P.S. use $json['test'] instead of $json[test], the first one causes syntax warning which PHP interprets as string "test" (in your case it's working:) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = json_decode($jsonString);

if($json["color"] == "blue"){
 ...
}

$json["language"] = "php";

$newJsonString = json_encode($json);
```

Isn't that easy?

Comment: The issue is that it is a multi-level tree. First I needed to find the correct test to put the student under and then add them to that level.

Comment: @Will I think $json["language"]["interpreted"] = "Java"; will work too!